# How to avoid unwanted lines of empty spaces on top of user control consists of 2D Buttons and Labels C# WPF

Tags: c#, arrays, button, alignment

For the last 3 weeks, I had been struggling to display an array of control which each user control basically comprised of 17 buttons and 2 labels. The current array size of 200 is for testing purposes only. Eventually, this piece of codes will have a programmable number of the array. 200 is also a good size to demonstrate the function of the scroll viewer. It was expected to display as follows:[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fax2G.png). The following actual output [Unwanted Spaces on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu7Im.png), have unwanted lines of spaces which requires me to scroll down in order to see the start of the first element of the set of buttons and labels.
Enclosed is the Codes for your kind attention.
I have been programming in C# on WPF for 9 months. I had been programming in VB for years, this is my first contributing in this forum after being a consumer of the forum.
Thank You in advance for any assistance.

```
<Window x:Class="Test_Array_Controls_2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Array_Controls_2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="auto" Background="AliceBlue">
        <local:UControlArray Grid.Row ="0"></local:UControlArray>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">QQ</Button>
        <Button Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">AA</Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
namespace Test_Array_Controls_2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}`


<UserControl x:Class="Test_Array_Controls_2.UControlArray"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Array_Controls_2"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="main" Width="auto" Height="auto">

</Grid></UserControl>`
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
namespace Test_Array_Controls_2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UControlArray.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UControlArray : UserControl
    {
        private Brush[] mCritBackColour = new Brush[2] { Brushes.LightGreen, Brushes.LightCyan }; //[0] left and [1] right
        public int defaultfontsize = 10;
        static int sz = 200;
        //Button[] btn = new Button[17];
        Button[,] btn = new Button[sz, 17];
        public UControlArray()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int x, y;
            double left = 0, top = 0;
            for (y = 0; y < sz; y++)
            {
                Label lblleft = new Label();
                lblleft.Width = 100;
                lblleft.Height = 32;
                lblleft.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
                lblleft.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                lblleft.Content = "Kiri";
                lblleft.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
                main.Children.Add(lblleft);
                left += lblleft.Width;
                for (x = 0; x < 17; x++)
                {

                    btn[y, x] = new Button();
                    //left += 72;
                    btn[y, x].HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    btn[y, x].Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
                    btn[y, x].Height = 32;
                    btn[y, x].Width = 32;
                    btn[y, x].Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Btn_click);
                    btn[y, x].Content = JMVal(x);
                    btn[y, x].ToolTip = Verbal(JMVal(x));
                    btn[y, x].FontSize = 14;
                    btn[y, x].Tag = y + ";" + x; //save information of the x and y
                    main.Children.Add(btn[y, x]);
                    left += 32;
                }
                //
                Label lblright = new Label();
                lblright.Width = 100;
                lblright.Height = 32;
                //left += 100;
                lblright.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
                lblright.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                lblright.Content = "Kanan";
                lblright.Background = Brushes.LightCyan;
                lblright.ToolTip = y;
                lblright.Tag = y;
                main.Children.Add(lblright);
                //
                left = 0;
                top += 64;
            }
        }
        private string Verbal(int i)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            string[] Verb = new string[10] { "", "equal", "equal to moderate", "moderate", "moderate to strong", "strong", "strong to very strong", "very strong", "very strong to extremely strong", "extremely strong" };
            return Verb[i];
        }

        //

        private int JMVal(int i) 
        {
            if (i >= 0 & i < 9)
            {
                return (9 - i);
            }
            else if (i >= 9 & i < 17)
            {
                return (i - 7);
            }
            else return 0;
        }
        private void Btn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            string[] InternalData = button.Tag.ToString().Split(';');

            ClearButtons(Convert.ToInt32(InternalData[0]));

            int idx = Convert.ToInt32(InternalData[1]);
            button.FontSize = 22;
            button.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;

            if (idx >= 0 & idx <= 7) { button.Background = mCritBackColour[0]; }
            else if (idx >= 9 & idx <= 17) { button.Background = mCritBackColour[1]; }
            else if (idx == 8) { button.Background = Brushes.OrangeRed; }

        }

        private void ClearButtons(int rw)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 17; i++)
            {
                btn[rw, i].FontSize = defaultfontsize; // defaultfontsize;
                btn[rw, i].Background = Brushes.LightGray;
                btn[rw, i].FontWeight = FontWeights.Light;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what is causing it, but it seems that the size of the space is equal to `(sz - 1) * 64`.  The fewer rows of buttons you add, the smaller the space.

Comment: I know there is a relationship but I am baffled for a reason. I had tried many ways of designing the usercontrol but aligning these controls using WPF is a problem. I am redeveloping my own software from  VB 6.0 .  The usercontrol then was much easier to develop, Could it be a bug in the complier? I have tried to change to the container grid with stackpanel and even canvas, but the outcome is not what I wanted. This approach is similar to what I had expected but with unwanted lines.

Answer (score 0):

To compensate for the unwanted size at the top I have added an extra few lines to shift the grid container, main to the top of negative (sz-1) * 32, as follows:

> ```
> {
>
>                 `enter code here`left = 0;
>                 top += 64;
>             }
>             //interim measure since there seems to be (sz-1) *64 added to the grid container at the top
>             **double tp = (sz - 1) * 32;
>             main.Margin= new Thickness(0,-tp,0,0);**
> ```